# How to draw a circle in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsbutton

I am trying a draw a circle with a background colour in my NSTableview's view based cell. I tried so many options none works fine.

I used a NSView subclass and clipped circular path in drawRect method. It worked, But whenever I scroll the table view it shape wasn't circular anymore.

```
CGContextRef context = (CGContextRef) [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:dirtyRect xRadius:10.0 yRadius:5.0];
[path addClip];
// Fill in background Color
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(backgroundColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, components[0],components[1],components[2],components[3]);
CGContextFillRect(context, NSRectToCGRect(dirtyRect));
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];
```

I also tried using beveled buttons(rounded) but when I set the background colour to its cell it was not round. It became a square.

```
    [result.tagImageButton.cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[self bounds]` instead of `dirtyRect`. As the scroll view scrolls, your cell may be asked to only draw parts of itself. In that case `dirtyRect` is smaller than your cell. In that case it is OK though to still draw the entire cell.